# Organizing and obtaining averages in a DF by a group. R

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have the following data structure:

```
iid <- c(rep("I1", 5), rep("I2", 5), rep("I3", 5), rep("I4", 5))
days <- c(-2,-3,0,-1,-5,-1,1,2,1,1,-2,2,2,-3,8,0,0,0,2,1)
val <- c(22,30,41,52,21,32,41,54,21,45,
         11,10,12,15,58,55,32,68,74,85)
data <- data.frame(iid = iid, days = days, val = val)
```

I need to obtain a new DF summarizing different information:

1. Grouping by iid, which is the day (in absolute value) close to 0: For iid = I1 would be 0, for iid = I2 would be 1, for iid = I3 would be 2.
2. Select those days close to 0. In iid = I1 would be row = 3. For iid = I2 would be rows = 6,7,9 and 10.
3. According to step 2 obtain the main value of variable "val" in case different rows were selected for each iid. For example, for I2 should be the average of 32,41,21 and 45 = 34.75.
4. Obtain a new DF with the outcome

So, the resulting data frame should look like this:

```
iid<-c("I1","I2","I3","I4")
days_r<-c(0,1,2,0)
val_r<-c(41,34.75,11,51.667)
data <- data.frame(iid = iid, days = days_r, val = val_r)
```

I tried to obtain the first step, select the days close to 0. However, I failed, badly.
I used this:

```
data_b <- data %>%
  group_by(iid) %>% 
  which(abs(days-0)==min(abs(days-0)))
ungroup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to wrap the `which` location index within `slice` to subset the rows, and then do the `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(iid) %>% 
   slice( which(abs(days-0)==min(abs(days-0)))) %>%
   summarise(val = mean(val))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  iid     val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 I1     41  
2 I2     34.8
3 I3     11  
4 I4     51.7
```

---

It may be also written as

```
data %>%
     group_by(iid) %>% 
     slice_min(n = 1, order_by = abs(days)) %>%
     summarise(val = mean(val))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  iid     val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 I1     41  
2 I2     34.8
3 I3     11  
4 I4     51.7
```

---

If we need the 'days' column as well, in the `summarise` (which is flexible in expanding the data as it can return more than one row per group), get the `unique` 'days' as well

```
data %>%
     group_by(iid) %>% 
     slice_min(n = 1, order_by = abs(days)) %>%
     summarise(days = unique(days), val = mean(val), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  iid    days   val
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 I1        0  41  
2 I2       -1  34.8
3 I2        1  34.8
4 I3       -2  11  
5 I3        2  11  
6 I4        0  51.7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain to me whether ungroup is needed?

Comment: @Cebs with only one grouping variable, the default option is `drop_last`.  So, it is already removed  or you can specify the `.groups = 'drop'` in `summarise` itself

Comment: Awesome! Thaks!

Comment: How can I add the variable day (in absolute value) to the final data.frame? I just need that to complete my results... I can't get it

Comment: @Cebs just change the `summarise` to `summarise(days, val = mean(val))` it will expand the rows because there are more than one 'days' per group or may be you need to `unique` i.e. `summarise(days = unique(days), val = mean(val))`